# Stripping unwanted data from an Array in php

Tags: php, slice

This code builds an array:

```
$size = sizeof($include_quotes);
  for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    $quotes = $GLOBALS[$include_quotes[$i]]->quote($method);
    if (is_array($quotes)) $quotes_array[] = $quotes;
  }
}
```

If i

```
print_r($quotes_array);
```

i get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => advshipper [methods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1-0-0 [title] => Trade Shipping [cost] => 20 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2-0-0 [title] => 1-2 working days [cost] => 3.2916666666667 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 4-0-0 [title] => 2-3 working days [cost] => 2.4916666666667 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 8-0-0 [title] => Click & Collect [cost] => 0 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 3 ) ) [module] => Shipping [tax] => 20 ) )
```

In some circumstances, I only want the data in field `0` to be passed onto the next part of the code. However, using

```
 $sliced_quotes_array = array_slice($quotes_array,0,1);
```

Still returns all the results.

What is the correct method to get just:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => advshipper [methods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1-0-0 [title] => Trade Shipping [cost] => 20 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 0 )
```

Any help greatly appreciated because i have tried numerous different ways and no luck yet.

Using the following still returns the same results

```
$testarray = array(0 => $quotes_array[0]);
print_r($testarray);
```

Comment: `$wantedStuff = quotesArray[0];` ?

Comment: There are nested arrays in your Json data,which array index are you referring to ?

Comment: @ChrisCooney No, doesn't work

Comment: @dreamweiver Everything within the 0 indices, As shown at the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some reading on arrays and after a bit of trial, i found a solution to my problem.

I used:

```
unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][1]);
```

By changing the index number after methods i was able to drop any shipping options i didn't require, whilst still maintaining the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the array constructor and explicitly include what you need:

```
array(0 => $quotes_array[0]);
```

Comment: You mean like this? $testarray = array(0 => $quotes_array[0]); But it still returns all the same results when i print_r the new array. Sorry, not too hot on php and learning as i go along

Comment: that's definitely not what should happen. are you certain you're print_r'ing the right array?

Comment: I'll edit the original question with further information so i can format it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your array:

[image]

When you are saying " I only want the data in field 0 to be passed onto the next part of the code", you meant that you only want this data to be passed next, right? :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => advshipper
        [module] => Shipping
        [tax] => 20
    )
)
```

Is this what you want?

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($quotes_array[0] as $items)
{
    if (!is_array($items))
    {
        $newArray[] = $items;
    }

}
```

`$newArray` will contain that data.

**UPDATE**

Okay, gotcha.
You can just use this:

`$newArray = $quotes_array[0]['methods'][0];`

Comment: I need only [0] => Array ( [id] => 1-0-0 [title] => Trade Shipping [cost] => 20 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 0.

Comment: That's perfect. Can i ask you, how would i go about displaying all EXCEPT  the first, i.e. stripping out the above results so that the remaining ones are still in the array

Comment: Well, that was false hope, because while your answer does return the values expected, the process now fails because it doesn't have the other data i.e. Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => advshipper [methods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( at the start and [module] => Shipping [tax] => 20 ) ) at the end. So somehow, i need to JUST strip out the unwanted data, leaving the rest intact.